# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, minidump

Can anyone explain me how `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` method works in minidump?

Answer (score 2):

There is some sample code to write a minidump here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416349%28VS.85%29.aspx

Basically you call SetUnhandledExceptionFilter and pass a pointer to a function like 'GenerateDump' in that sample code. And when your app crashes it writes the dump out.